# g++ compiler error on deleted assignment operator of pair<string,string>

Tags: c++11, stl

I think the following reduced C++11 code should be valid.

```
unordered_map<string,string> test;
auto it = remove_if( test.begin(), test.end(),
    [] (const decltype(test)::value_type &entry) { return true; } );
```

But it fails to compile with g++ 6.3, complaining about a deleted assignment operator of std::pair, but AFAIK that operator is not deleted.

```
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:868:16: error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=( ...
*__result = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__first);
```

Is this a compiler/glibc bug or is the code really invalid for some reason I fail to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::pair<const string, string>` *does* have deleted assignment operator(s), because you can't change `first`.

The `key_type` of all the map-like containers in the STL are const, because otherwise you could break the lookup of elements.

Comment: Can't @mention you on my own answer: thanks for the edit, indeed is_assignable requires both the type of assigned and assignee.

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at [remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) documentation:

> The type of dereferenced ForwardIt must meet the requirements of [MoveAssignable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveAssignable).

That is, “given `t`, a modifiable lvalue expression of type `T` and `rv`, an rvalue expression of type `T`, the expression `t = rv` must be valid and [behave as expected]”.

Here, you pass `unordered_map<string, string>`'s iterator to `remove_if`. Let's have a look. According to [`unordered_map` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map),

> `value_type` is defined as `std::pair<const Key, T>`

So, `std::pair<const string, string>`.

Let's look at pair's [`operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator%3D). Most notably:

> `template< class U1, class U2 >
>   pair& operator=( const pair<U1,U2>& other );` does not participate in overload resolution unless `std::is_assignable_v<first_type&, const U1&>` and `std::is_assignable_v<second_type&, const U2&>` are both true.

Here, [`std::is_assignable_v<const string&, const string&>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable) is not true, therefore the operator is not available. Therefore the pair is not MoveAssignable. Therefore `remove_if` cannot be used on those iterators.

So that would make your code invalid.

Comment: The two answers nicely supplement each other, unfortunately I couldn't accept both, so I accepted the summarized one but also voted this up.

Comment: Caleth's answer is nice as well because it's more concise and explains why the standard chose the approach I followed in mine. Thanks for the intention :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a need to assign to a `std::pair<A const, B>` that was a copy of something I got by dereferencing a `std::map<A,B>` iterator. I finally used destructor/constructor logic.

```
// For the placement allocator
#include <new>
...
typedef std::pair<A const, B> PairType;
PairType &rPairWrite(...some source...);
PairType const &rPairRead(...some source...);
// rPairWrite = rPairRead;
rPairWrite.~PairType();
new (&rPairWrite) PairType (someAValue, someBValue);
```

Stupid syntax games...